# ImportError when importing spaCy using Spyder

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, importerror, spacy

I'm still new to Python. I'm having issues when importing spaCy in python (v2.7) which doesn't appear when using it in ipython (v5.4.1). I used to have spaCy 2.0.11 then I reinstalled 2.0.7 and the issue remains.

Some useful info about the spaCy model and python version I have :

```
Python version     2.7.14         
    Platform           Darwin-15.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
    spaCy version      2.0.7          
    Location           /Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy
    Models             en_core_web_sm, en_default
```

Thinc version:

```
Name: thinc
Version: 6.10.2
```

Doing `import spacy` and other imports using ipython doesnt cause any problems, and when using python interpreter in terminal:

```
python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct  5 2017, 02:28:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
>>> import thinc
>>> import thinc.neural
>>> from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
>>> exit()
```

This is my code:

```
import re
import string
import math
from itertools import chain
from spacy.en import English '''Error triggered here'''
```

However, using Spyder IDE first throws this error:

```
  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 499, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 124, in _compile
    raise CompileError, msg

ImportError: Building module thinc.neural.optimizers failed: ['ImportError: Building module thinc.neural.ops failed: ["CompileError: command \'gcc\' failed with exit status 1\\n"]\n']
```

Then in the second compile the error is changed and remains the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-3743c1a24668>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/AMAL/p1', wdir='/Users/AMAL')

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/AMAL/p1", line 14, in <module>
    from spacy.en import English

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .link import link

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 11, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import copy_array

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model

  File "/Users/AMAL/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .. import util

ImportError: cannot import name util
```

How can I fix this problem? what could be the problem? I'm super interested in including spaCy in my work, so any help will be truly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post your code that is causing the error when run in the IDE?

Comment: @RThomP I'm importing a library that one of it's classes has` from spacy.lang.en import English` which is the root of the problem. This the link of the file I'm using https://github.com/wikilinks/nel/blob/master/nel/features/recognition.py .

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to be able to provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RThomP Done, question is edited.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please update Spyder to its latest version (3.2.8) and try again.

Comment: @carlos-cordoba ah thank you for the insight. I want to make sure I update correctley, do I update by typing in terminal 'conda update spyder'.

Comment: Yes, that's the right command to use.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba sorry for taking a long time I got busy with other stuff. This worked like a charm, thank you so much. Could you write it as an answer so I can select it as one. Thanks again :)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba could you please take a look at this issue which appeared after some updating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584217/image-not-found-error-when-launching-spyder-and-jupyternotebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem seems related to an already reported [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299) in Spyder, which was fixed in our **3.2.8** version (released in March/2018).