# Launching Spyder and JupyterNotebook causes importError when image not found

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder, conda

I'm new to python and the virtual environment stuff. I'm facing issues opening jupyter notebook and Spyder after updating conda.

Here are some info about the versions I have:

```
 $ conda info

     active environment : None  '''is it caused by this ? '''
       user config file : /Users/-/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/-/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 2.7.14.final.0
       base environment : /Users/-/anaconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /Users/-/anaconda2/pkgs
                          /Users/-/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/-/anaconda2/envs
                          /Users/-/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.14 Darwin/15.5.0 OSX/10.11.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


JupyerNotebook version : 5.5.0
Jupyter version : 4.4.0
Spyder version : 3.2.8
```

Spyder fails to launch and when trying to launch spyder from anaconda navigator I get this error:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/-/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
    Referenced from: /Users/-/anaconda2/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
    Reason: image not found

Trying to launch jupyter notebook from anaconda throws the same `image not found` error:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/**init**.py", line 6, in 
        from . import (constants, error, message, context,
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/-/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libsodium.23.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/-/anaconda2/lib/libzmq.5.dylib
      Reason: image not found

I found out that after updating, a new Anaconda2 folder was initialized for only the `zmq` file `/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cffi/__pycache__`.

Everything was working smoothly but after following anaconda instructions and recommendations to update I started getting those errors.

How can I resolve this issue? Is it because the `active environment : None`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faced same issue. From https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1632 it explained that some dependencies when updating conda are messed up so try:

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

Then try:

```
conda update conda-build
```

Good luck,

Comment: Be aware that will remove all your custome dependencies installed, plus Jupyter notebook, jupyterLab, etc. At least it happend to me :(